# What ncurses frameworks are available for BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, ncurses, tui, bash4

Are there some more Text User Interface (TUI) frameworks for bash (other than this)? : http://code.google.com/p/bashsimplecurses/

- I want to take user input (data entry)
- process the entry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need to do is prompt the user for information, take a look at `dialog`.

http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html

Answer (score 1):

`bashsimplecurses` is pretty capable (from the little I've seen), but you might want to try [GTK Server](http://www.gtk-server.org/). (Have a look at the docs page for tutorial and manual links). It can work with [a large number of scripting languages](http://www.gtk-server.org/intro.html). Other Stack Exchange users (particularly the [UNIX/ BSD/ GNU/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) lot) recommend using ncurses with Python.