# How do I read any one key in Bash?

Tags: bash, keyboard

I can get `read -n 1 KEY` to get most keys, except for keys which are represented by multiple characters. For example, if I press the up arrow key:

```
$ read -n 1; echo
^[[A
$ [A
```

As you can see, `read` only takes the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and the `[A` is left over.

What I want to be able to do in a script is:

1. Go through a list with the arrow keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to do something with it
2. For other actions, press different keys.

Comment: Ncurses is a library to make such console interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876008/what-ncurses-frameworks-are-available-for-bash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are better off using dialog as jm666 mentioned, but there are other ways to skin that cat.

```
read -n 1 x; while read -n 1 -t .1 y; do x="$x$y"; done
```

Basically wait until you read a character and then spin consuming input until .1 seconds has passed w/o input.

Warning, fast typists could get annoyed.  You might need to tweak that timeout.

Comment: @bi99l35: I guess 2400 baud dialup connections are pretty rare, so that should be safe.

Comment: Still not good when you copy&paste some text.  Then no timeout is fast enough to detect this.  We should use the terminfo to find out whether we have a multibyte keypress at hand.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (linux) when the character is Enter or Space or Tab. It does work for Backspace and even Esc, though.

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer to your question - but the way of solution:

You probably should check the "dialog" utility for creating "ncurses" (screen oriented) dialog boxes from the shell. see: http://hightek.org/dialog/

Google form some examples, or check: http://unstableme.blogspot.sk/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html