# How to run a function on first keystroke in bash/zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to run a function when I start typing in the terminal.

Specifically I want to run the `fzf` function, for which I currently need to press `ctrl-r` to trigger it. I would like `any keystroke to trigger it` so history always appears when I type.

`Only the first keystroke` should run the function, because running it multiple time toggles between path and filename selection.

Comment: Interesting. Thoughts: [`bind`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800) probably won't work, as I don't think you can meet the "first keystroke only" requirement.  A faux command line with a high speed [read loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596059) might work.  Using the terminal in [raw mode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18334/) or modifying the [bash source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git) are probably the most likely avenues.  Also, consider [selector](http://www.idiap.ch/~fleuret/software.html#selector) instead of fzf.

Answer (score 1):

I have bound the `Up` and `Down` arrow keys to `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` respectively. So when I type something and then press `Up` or `Down`, it does a history search starting with typed letters. This works for me as I don't want to do a history search for every command entered.

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it's close.

```
# Bind up and down arrows to do backward and forward history search
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
    bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but I think I still prefer using ctrl-r to the arrow keys.

Comment: Sure. One advantage of this is you can search through history after you've typed few letters. `Ctrl-r` needs to be fired before typing anything. But yeah, different strokes for different folks.

Comment: Unrelated, but I prefer `up-line-or-search` and `down-line-or-search` for up and down arrows. This has the additional advantage of "search backward/forward in the history for a line beginning with the first word in the buffer" over the default (very similar to `history-search-backward`) And I use `history-incremental-search-backward` and `history-incremental-search-forward` for `C-r` and `C-s`.